# Hetman movement in array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to reproduce movement of hetman in my array. I took a shoot at vertical movement only.

There are only 3 different pawns (1,2,3)

So basically, I need to trigger loop that scans every cell and if no other pawns occur then place 1 (hetman number) in the right spot. And if occurs just break the loop and force the user to input cords correctly. And here is a problem, I don't know how to do it with `for`, `while`, `if`, etc. Hope I explained it well.

```cpp
if (vertical==vertical_t)   // Movement only horizontal , t means last position , vertical- picked by player 
{
    if (horizontal_t<horizontal)   // from left to right movement , t stands for last position again  ( always will be )
    {
        for (int j=horizontal_t+1;j<horizontal_c;j++)    // checking every cell to the right  for other pawns
        {
            if ((board[vertical][j]==1)||(board[vertical][j]==3)||(board[vertical][j]==2))  // 1 is other hetman  2,3 , stand for other pawns ( cant get pass them , move is impossible)
                cout << " move is impossible" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "_And if occurs just break the loop_" - Did you try `break;` to break the loop?

Comment: For those of us who aren't Polish, "hetman" refers to the Queen piece in Chess, right? (had to look that up).

Comment: Oh sry , I thought that hetman is international , my bad

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it . Sry for polish letter but there is way to many to change. Works in vertical and horizontal . Across is yet to be done :)

```
 if (plansza[pionowy_t][poziomy_ct]!=1)
        cout << "Na tym polu nie ma twojego pionka !"<< endl;
    else {
        cout << " wprowadz ruch jaki chcesz wykonac ( w pionie i poziomie) " << endl;
    cin >> pionowy >> poziomy;
    Konwersja (pionowy,poziomy,poziomy_c);

    }}while (plansza[pionowy_t][poziomy_ct]!=1);

 if (Sprawdz_poprawnosc(plansza,pionowy_t,poziomy_ct,pionowy,poziomy_c))
 {
     plansza[pionowy_t][poziomy_ct]=0;
     plansza[pionowy][poziomy_c]=1;
 }


}
bool Sprawdz_poprawnosc (int plansza[10][10], int pionowy_t, int poziomy_ct,int pionowy,int poziomy_c)
{
    if (pionowy==pionowy_t)  {
            if (poziomy_ct<poziomy_c)
            {
                for (int j=poziomy_ct+1;j<=poziomy_c;j++)
                    {
                    if ((plansza[pionowy][j]==1)||(plansza[pionowy][j]==3)||(plansza[pionowy][j]==2)){
                            cout << " nie mozna przeprowadzic takiego ruchu , cos stoi na drodze" << endl;
                            return false;}
                            }
                return true;
            }
            if (poziomy_ct>poziomy_c)
            {
                for (int j=poziomy_ct-1;j>=poziomy_c;j--)
                    {
                    if ((plansza[pionowy][j]==1)||(plansza[pionowy][j]==3)||(plansza[pionowy][j]==2)){
                            cout << " nie mozna przeprowadzic takiego ruchu , cos stoi na drodze" << endl;
                            return false;}
                            }
                return true;
            }

    }
     if (poziomy_c==poziomy_ct)
     {
         if (pionowy_t<pionowy)
            {
                for (int j=pionowy_t+1;j<=pionowy;j++)
                    {
                    if ((plansza[poziomy_c][j]==1)||(plansza[poziomy_c][j]==3)||(plansza[poziomy_c ][j]==2)){
                            cout << " nie mozna przeprowadzic takiego ruchu , cos stoi na drodze" << endl;
                            return false;}
                            }
                return true;
            }


         if (pionowy_t>pionowy)
            {
                for (int j=pionowy+1;j<=pionowy_t;j--)
                    {
                    if ((plansza[j][poziomy_c]==1)||(plansza[j][poziomy_c]==3)||(plansza[j][poziomy_c]==2)){
                            cout << " nie mozna przeprowadzic takiego ruchu , cos stoi na drodze" << endl;
                            return false;}
                            }
                return true;
            }



     }


}
```